# How come Fin Raziel aged so much while she was transformed as an unnaturally long-lived possum?

Tags: willow

In the movie [*Willow*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096446/) (1988), Fin Raziel has been turned into a possum and trapped on an island by the Big Bad, evil queen Bavmorda.

She's been trapped there for around 15 years, since Bavmorda took control of Tir Asleen.  Sorsha is 18 in the present time (according to the novelization) and according to Cherlindrea's tale, Fin Raziel was transformed during her fight with Bavmorda at the time the latter abandoned Tir Asleen, when Sorsha was a young child (but no longer a baby).

Fin Raziel's transformed body has apparently not aged or at least aged very slowly, since she has lived far beyond the maximum lifespan of a possum.  "Possums" normally have a lifespan in the wild of 2 years for American species and typically 4-6 (though potentially up to 12) for species from Australia/New Guinea.

Given that her transformed body has apparently been magically preserved, why does Fin Raziel's human form apparently age even while she is in animal form?  In fact it seems that she aged more while transformed than the number of elapsed years would suggest.  The chronology is a bit squishy - Cherlindrea's retelling doesn't say exactly how many years elapsed between Bavmorda's seducing the prince and the birth of Sorsha - but Fin Raziel was younger than Bavmorda (Fin Raziel was the youngest sorcerer) and Bavmorda wouldn't reasonably have been much past 30 when Sorsha was born.  That makes Fin Raziel somewhere between 35 and 45 years old, with maybe 5 years of error.  But in the movie she is portrayed as far older than her actual age would be - [Patricia Hayes](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0371175/mediaindex?ref_=nm_phs_md_sm) who played Fin Raziel was 78 when the movie was filmed!

The novelization describes her as an old woman with white hair, shrunken and wrinkled; even allowing for mediaeval aging, that's a bit much for a woman at worst in her 50s.  So why is she suddenly so old?

Comment: Completely wild guess: perhaps she aged in “dog years.” The possum became very old for a possum, so she was restored as a proportionately very old woman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the novelization and loved the movie, yet it never occurred to me to question this. Hmm. I will say that it is one of the movie's [best moments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jj7L4ENaq8w) when Raziel, transformed back into human form, examines her aged hands, says plaintively, "Has it been so long?", and then dismisses these concerns. "Willow," she declaims. "We have work to do."

Well. We have work to do. If, as you say, Fin Raziel is the youngest sorceress, then the evil Bavmorda is older. Therefore they were both fairly old when Bavmorda transformed Raziel. Bavmorda is very well-preserved, but this is evidently the result of powerful magic, for the mask slips during her convocation of evil toward the end. Look at Bavmorda's face in her [fight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QZbglXZ298) with Raziel. Even without preservative spells, Bavmorda could have been up to 45 years old or so when she had her child Sorsha. Fin Raziel might have been 40. Add 20 or so years in a medieval culture, and she might be a more reasonable 60. Add preservative magic for each, and they could be even older.

Comment: I don't necessarily think you're wrong, but if she remembered herself as young before her transformation, I don't think 15 years elapsed should make her _old_.

Comment: True, Raziel-in-possum-form did refer to herself as having been young and beautiful before Bavmorda transformed her. Shall we chalk it up to inconsistent writing, as usual?